# Why magento 2 auto add referer to link login?

Tags: magento2

When i try open login link, it always add referer/... to link login. Why is it happen? and how can i remove it?
example:
http://m222sample4.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL20yMjJzYW1wbGU0LmNvbS9jdXN0b21lci9hY2NvdW50L2xvZ2luLw%2C%2C/

Comment: why do you want to remove it?

Comment: My customer want remove it.

Comment: @Piyush because that pages is indexed by google, same page but with different referer. And that will give many duplicates of the same page indexed.

Comment: @electroid too late for you but not for others: the login url should not be indexed. You should use the robots.txt to blacklist this url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature provided by Magento. It is used to redirect a user back to the page where he tried to login to resume his navigation. If a user is on a category page and clicks on login link, it will add category page as referrer in URL and will redirect the user back to the same category page after successful login.

If you want to remove this feature, there is a configuration in admin panel. Go to

**Stores > Configurations > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options**

Set `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging` in to `Yes` and you will not see referrer in the URL anymore. But this will always redirect a user to customer dashboard after login.

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Referer Param has encoded url as value, the url  from which customer was transferred to login page is added as referer, so after login customer can be redirected to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

https://prnt.sc/whb205

https://prnt.sc/whb2fg

Please set 'Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in' option as YES